# Solve the following complex number: $\frac{1 + i\tan \theta}{1 - i\tan\theta}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I solve the following complex number?

$$\frac{1 + i\tan \theta}{1 - i\tan\theta}$$

I know how to solve arithmetic problems with complex numbers, but this is the first time I have a function and variable inside.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is to be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using: $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$ ([De-moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula))

$$\frac{1+i\tan\theta}{1-i\tan\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}{\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}}=e^{i2\theta}=\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta$$